# Change activity transition when inside a TabHost

Tags: android, transition, android-animation

I have successfully changed the transitions between activities using `overridePendingTransition()`.

Unfortunately when I am on a `TabActivity` and use activities inside each tab. When one of those activities inside the content of the tab, starts another activity, the `overridePendingTransition()` seems to not work.

I basically have a `TabActivity`, inside it resides an activity with a `ListView`. What I'm doing is when the item is clicked, I launch the item details' activity.

This new activity's transition animation is not being overridden with the `overridePendingTransition()`

I basically do this:

```
private Activity owner;
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent programActivity = new Intent().setClass(view.getContext(), ProgramActivity.class);
    Program program = (Program) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    programActivity.putExtra("programID", program.getId());
    owner.startActivity(programActivity);
    owner.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
}
```

So, I believe that the pending transition is overridden after I'm trying to override them.

Is there a different place I should do that?
Am I doing some other stupid mistake?

Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out that the problem was because my view was a sub-activity inside a tab.

To correctly override the transitions I've overridden the `onPause` method on the `TabActivity` and it now works as expected.

Note: You still have to use the `overridePendingTransition()` on the listener for your items if your activity is NOT within a tab.

Comment: Works very well. Saved me the time to restructure the entire TabActivity.

Comment: I put the overridePendingTransition() in the onPause() of my tabhost.  I'm not sure if that's what you meant or not but it worked for me.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I did too.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem with calling overridePendingTransition() from within a Fragment, because Fragments do not have overridePendingTransition() method defined.

I solved it using:

```
getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enterAnim, R.anim.exitAnim);
```

Hope it helps. The Fragment was within a TabHost.